# Change cellsize of ArcInfo Grid ASCII data

Tags: esri-grid-format, cell-size

I have a ArcInfo Grid ASCII file of Turkey with cellsize 0.000833333333 (3 arc second ~90m for equator and ~83m for Turkey, I've learned so far), Can I just simply change the header value to 83m or is there any proper way to change cell size to an integer number. How can I do that?

ncols        24001 
nrows        12001 
xllcorner    24.999583987092 
yllcorner    34.999583575447 
cellsize     0.000833333333 
NODATA_value -9999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO**, you can't just edit that file! If you change the cell size then you are changing the size of the imagery which will cause all of the cells in the image to move.

If you need (for some reason) to have your grid in metres then you need to reproject it using a GIS tool.